# SQL: Inner join which its WHERE clause contains CHARINDEX() - Improve performence

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance, sql-server-performance

I'm have two tables: A and B, each of them contains strings.
I need to find all the matches between table A and table B when the string of table A contains the string of table B (B.stringColumn is substring of A.stringColumn).

I did it by the following code using `CHARINDEX()` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE CHARINDEX(B.stringColumn, A.stringColumn) > 0
```

Is there more efficient way to do so?

This tables may contain massive amount of data, that why i'm asking this question.

Thanks in advance,
Nuriel

Comment: I believe that if you are just doing a search on a substring anywhere in another string only full-text indexing can help (not too familiar with FTI though).  If it's a case of a string starting with a substring then you can take advantage of the index on the target column.  I would use the syntax: A.stringColumn LIKE %B.stringColumn% and see if the execution plan is able to use indexes.

Answer (score 2):

I would be more inclined to phrase this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON A.stringColumn LIKE '%' + B.stringColumn + '%';
```

Alas, that does not help performance at all.  The problem is that looking for patterns in the middle of a string cannot make use of optimizations or any other techniques.  You are stuck with nested loop join algorithms.

In some cases, you might be able to use a [full text index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).  This can be a bit challenging when joining between two tables.

There is a *technical* solution to this problem.  It involves indexes built on something called n-grams (say, 3-character combinations).  However, SQL Server does not support this indexing type.

Comment: Out of curiosity what RDBMS supports these indexes?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu . . . Postgres (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-indexes.html).  Other databases might have extensions that support them.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you can use LIKE operator. This will not maybe give you some significant performance upgrade, but it has a chance of using index (if there is an index on that column), while with functions in where clause, indexes will never be used.